# How to debug Arduino files with Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, arduino, codeblocks

I'm developing an Arduino project and I do need to test it in a test environment where I simulate sensor reads. I do this in c++ and I wrote a (very rough) port of the project in c++. Working in Code::Blocks and compiling with mingw

Everything works fine but I cannot debug it since Code::Blocks/gdb does not recognize the .ino files as proper source files and so it does not break at breakpoints. For debugging the code I need to copy and paste my code into main.cpp

Before

```
#include "..\finestra\finestra.ino"


int main()
{
    setup();
    while(counter < 540) loop();
    return 0;
}
```

After

```
[my whole Arduino source pasted here]


int main()
{
    setup();
    while(counter < 540) loop();
    return 0;
}
```

which is kind of uncomfortable

Two questions:

1. How do I tell Code::Blocks / gdb that finestra.ino is a source file to be treaded as a cpp file?
2. Are there better solutions to test and debug my Arduino code?

Answer (score 0):

No one?

I'm answering myself for anybody who could need this in the future.

What I tried so fare are this two things:

1. There is a fork of Code::Blocks which is thought to deal with Arduino. The homepage is http://arduinodev.com/codeblocks/. All tools needed should be there (I still need to try it thoroughly). You need a second Code::Blocks IDE installed on the same computer, but it is a reasonable trade off
2. I updated my gdb.exe to version 7.7. With that breakpoints in files .ino do work, even if not perfectly (the program stops at the breakpoint but does not show you grafically where it is, you have to find it in the logs, which is kind of uncomfortable but at least it works!)

Either way it is possible to debug, although with drawbacks